# How to iterate over regexp compliant strings

Tags: java, regex, algorithm, iterator

What is the easiest way to implement a class (in Java) that would serve as an iterator over the set of all values which conform to a given regexp?

Let's say I have a class like this:

```
public class RegexpIterator
{
  private String regexp;

  public RegexpIterator(String regexp) {
    this.regexp = regexp;
  }

  public abstract boolean hasNext() {
    ...
  }

  public abstract String next() {
    ...
  }
}
```

How do I implement it? The class assumes some linear ordering on the set of all conforming values and the next() method should return the i-th value when called for the i-th time.

Ideally the solution should support full regexp syntax (as supported by the Java SDK).

---

To avoid confusion, please note that the class is not supposed to iterate over matches of the given regexp over a given string. Rather it should (eventually) enumerate all string values that conform to the regexp (i.e. would be accepted by the matches() method of a matcher), without any other input string given as argument.

---

To further clarify the question, let's show a simple example.

```
RegexpIterator it = new RegexpIterator("ab?cd?e");
while (it.hasNext()) {
  System.out.println(it.next());
}
```

This code snippet should have the following output (the order of lines is not relevant, even though a solution which would list shorter strings first would be preferred).

```
ace
abce
ecde
abcde
```

---

Note that with some regexps, such as `ab[A-Z]*cd`, the set of values over which the class is to iterate is ininite. The preceeding code snippet would run forever in these cases.

Comment: There are many many ways - especially since the requirement is not very clear to me. Best would be to try something, and ask when you have a problem. This looks like a code request (with very vague requirements), and not a question to me.

Comment: I did not expect any code in return, rather just some links libraries which support this functionality or to descriptions of recommended algorithms.

Comment: Please give a simple input/output exampe...

Comment: what if the regex were `ab[A-Z]*cd` ? Post the output when you're done.

Comment: I have augmented the question with some additional information to clarify the problem, including the requested examples. In case it still was not clear, please feel free to ask any other questions.

Comment: According to [Georg Cantor](http://io9.com/5873581/the-odd-genius-who-showed-that-one-infinity-was-greater-than-another), the infinity represented by `.*` would be greater than the infinity represented by `ab[A-Z]*cd`. Just sayin'. ;) Pursuing this line of thought too far, however, may drive you mad.

Answer (score 3):

Do you need to implement a class? This pattern works well:

```
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[0-9]+");
    Matcher m = p.matcher("123, sdfr 123kjkh 543lkj ioj345ljoij123oij");
    while (m.find()) {
        System.out.println(m.group());
    }
```

output:

```
123
123
543
345
123
```

for a more generalized solution:

```
public static List<String> getMatches(String input, String regex) {
    List<String> retval = new ArrayList<String>();
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile(regex);
    Matcher m = p.matcher(input);
    while (m.find()) {
        retval.add(m.group());
    }
    return retval;
}
```

which then can be used like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<String> matches = getMatches("this matches _all words that _start _with an _underscore", "_[a-z]*");
    for (String s : matches) { // List implements the 'iterable' interface
        System.out.println(s);
    }
}
```

which produces this:

```
_all
_start
_with
_underscore
```

more information about the Matcher class can be found here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html

Comment: I'm affraid I did not fully understand your solution. Is it capable of dealing with any given regexp (the value is given at run time rather than at compile time)? Also I'm looking for code to (eventually) enumerate all conforming values (without duplicates), not just some random values that conform.

Comment: I updated my answer with a more generalized solution, as for your use-case, you may want to check out the javadocs for Matcher. 'find()' returns weather or not there's another string that matches your regex in the input, and 'group()' returns that string. every time find is called, it moves on to the next substring.

Comment: The algorithm should only take the regexp as input, not the additional string. The class should iterate over all possible strings that conform to the given regexp, rather than just over substring matching a given string.

Comment: I have added some more information to the original question in order to make it less confusing.

Comment: Your problem has an unbounded and indeterminate growth rate, for example, the regex "[a]+" will produce an infinite number of strings. why do you need this?

Comment: I'm trying to find out an algorithm to assign values to elements of XML files that conform to a certain XML schema (see [my other question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17454327/1103412)). If you additionally set an upper bound on the length of the strings than the result set should always be finite. Modifying the general algorithm to only support strings up to a certain length should be easy.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another working example. It might be helpful :

```
public class RegxIterator<E> implements RegexpIterator {

private Iterator<E> itr = null;

public RegxIterator(Iterator<E> itr, String regex) {
    ArrayList<E> list = new ArrayList<E>();
    while (itr.hasNext()) {
        E e = itr.next();
        if (Pattern.matches(regex, e.toString()))
            list.add(e);
    }
    this.itr = list.iterator();
}

@Override
public boolean hasNext() {
    return this.itr.hasNext();
}

@Override
public String next() {
    return this.itr.next().toString();
}
```

}

If you want to use it for other dataTypes(*Integer,Float* etc. or other classes where *toString()* is meaningful), declare *next()* to return *Object* instead of *String*. Then you may able be to perform a typeCast on the return value to get back the actual type.

Comment: By the time I posted, you already edited your question. Anyway the string "ecde" in output doesn't match your regexp "ab?cd?e".
And if you expect ordering(ie-sorting) of the result, it will technically contradict the behavior of an iterator.

Comment: Plus I'd like to know how he plans to sort infinity.