# Looking for an algorithm to evaluate nodes of a graph

Tags: algorithm, graph

Let's suppose I have an undirected multi-graph, i.e. a (G, E) pair, where G is a finite set of nodes and E is a finite set of edges. I am looking for an algorithm that would assign a single string value to each node under the following constraints.

1.

Every node is given a (possibly empty) set of constraints that restrict permissible values. I'd like to support at least the following types of value constraints:

- min-length(x) (the value is at least the given number of characters long),
- max-length(x) (the value is at most the given number of characters long),
- regexp(x) (the value conforms to the given regular expression),
- numeric (the value consists of digits only).

Ideally it should be possible to add support for new types of constraints in future.

2.

There are two types of edges:

- different,
- same,

meaning that the concerned nodes should be assigned different/same values (meaning non-equal/equal strings).

3.

Finally every node can be assigned a (possibly empty) set of constraints of the following types:

- different-from(x),
- equal-to(x),

meaning that the given node should be assigned a value different from or equal to the given one.

---

I expect the algorithm to either report an inconsistency (if no such evaluation exists) or to return any (ideally a small one, i.e. one where the assigned values consist of a small number of characters) of the evaluations that meet the criteria (otherwise).

---

Please note that I don't expect you to provide a detailed description of an algorithm for me. I'd be grateful for any hints you could provide to get me on the right track.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few suggestions:

- You can simplify the problem by combining all nodes connected by "same" edges into a single node.  (Note that the constraints for this single node will be the union of all the individual constraints.)
- The reduced problem seems very similar to [graph colouring](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_coloring) as you need to choose labels for each node such that the labels are different for connected nodes.
- Unfortunately, graph colouring is NP complete so you may well struggle to get an efficient algorithm unless your number of nodes is quite small

> Graph coloring is computationally hard. It is NP-complete to decide if
>   a given graph admits a k-coloring for a given k except for the cases k
>   = 1 and k = 2. In particular, it is NP-hard to compute the chromatic number. The 3-coloring problem remains NP-complete even on planar
>   graphs of degree 4

- It may help to look at [greedy colouring algorithms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greedy_coloring) if you don't necessarily need a perfect solution

Comment: Thanks for your help. Add 1, would the set assigned to the new node really be an intersection of the original sets of constraints, or would it be a union?

Comment: You are quite right, union is the correct term not intersection, I'll edit the answer.